# How to properly import Java code style settings with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to import [Google's Java code style](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml) with IntelliJ.
The style file contains the following configuration:

```
<code_scheme name="GoogleStyle">
  <option name="JAVA_INDENT_OPTIONS">
    <value>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="8" />
      ...
    </value>
  </option>
  ...
</code_scheme>
```

But after the import my settings still show
**Tab size** 4 (instead of 8)
**Indent** 4 (instead of 2)
**Continuation indent** 8 (instead of 4)

When I export that style scheme then in the output file the values are the same as in the original file:

```
<option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
<option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
<option name="TAB_SIZE" value="8" />
```

Steps I took to import the style:

1. Navigate to *Settings* -> *Editor* -> *Code Style* -> *Java*
2. Click *Manage* button next to *Scheme* dropdown -> *Import...* -> *IntelliJ IDEA code style XML*
3. From the *Scheme* dropdown select the new option (called "GoogleStyle")
4. *Apply*

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2016.2.2

The expected result is that when I import the style then created style scheme has indent size (etc) the same as specified in the code scheme file.
How can I do that?

Comment: Easier way：install google-java-format plugin in Intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the format used in the configuration file differes from what IntelliJ (at least the version I'm using) expects.

I changed my code setting, exported them and looked for differences.
The ident setting were in the output file like so:

```
<code_scheme name="MyTestStyle">
    ...
    <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
        <indentOptions>
          <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
          <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
          <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="8" />
        </indentOptions>
    </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Importing this file worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED**
The file from Google uses an old (I suppose) key for filetype (java instead of Java). I have made the following changes and it works.

```
<ADDITIONAL_INDENT_OPTIONS fileType="JAVA">
  <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="2" />
  <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
  <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="8" />
  <option name="USE_TAB_CHARACTER" value="false" />
  <option name="SMART_TABS" value="false" />
  <option name="LABEL_INDENT_SIZE" value="0" />
  <option name="LABEL_INDENT_ABSOLUTE" value="false" />
  <option name="USE_RELATIVE_INDENTS" value="false" />
</ADDITIONAL_INDENT_OPTIONS>
```

I have made a fork of the GitHub repository with the file corrected (https://github.com/nhenneaux/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml).

---

The easiest way is to import the style file into `~/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/config/codestyles`. Then you have to restart Intellij and go in the style settings to select GoogleStyle.
[image]

Comment: This gave the same result as my original attempt i.e the identation settings didn't change. But some other setting were updated (e.g "Class count to use import with *")

Comment: It was an error into the style guide of Google. I have edited my answer.

Comment: That didn't work for me either but pointed me in the right direction.