# Source control intellij code style settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have a project being managed by more than 20 developers and most of them use intellij.
I was wondering if we can source an xml file somehow so that every developer doesn't have to import code style settings manually.

[How to properly import Java code style settings with IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019486/how-to-properly-import-java-code-style-settings-with-intellij?rq=1)
This thread suggests that we have to manually import the xml file and only then we will see those settings will come into effect. Is there a setting that can import the code styles automatically?

Comment: [Share your project files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) in version control, code style can be configured to be project specific and will be used automatically for every developer working on the same project. That is how it works for IntelliJ IDEA project itself.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.After i had made my desired codeStyle settings on my machine this is what the .idea/codestyleSettings.xml looks like
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
  <component name="ProjectCodeStyleSettingsManager">
    <option name="PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS">
      <value />
    </option>
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="mySettings" />
  </component>
</project>`
But, mySettings.xml is not included in the .idea directory. It is stored in Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2016.3/codestyles
This is why i am confused on how to source control it.

Comment: That is exactly how it works for codeStyle, developer opens a project and the project uses `.idea/codestyleSettings.xml` automatically. You don't need to import any code styles manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectCodeStyleSettingsManager">
    <option name="PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS">
      <value>
        <option name="CLASS_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="99" />
        <option name="NAMES_COUNT_TO_USE_IMPORT_ON_DEMAND" value="15" />
        <option name="IMPORT_LAYOUT_TABLE">
          <value>
            <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="true" />
            <emptyLine />
            <package name="java" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
            <emptyLine />
            <package name="javax" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
            <emptyLine />
            <package name="org" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
            <emptyLine />
            <package name="com" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
            <emptyLine />
            <package name="" withSubpackages="true" static="false" />
          </value>
        </option>
        <codeStyleSettings language="JAVA">
            <option name="KEEP_LINE_BREAKS" value="false" />
            <option name="KEEP_FIRST_COLUMN_COMMENT" value="false" />
        </codeStyleSettings>
      </value>
    </option>
    <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
  </component>
</project>
```

The above settings in .idea/codestyleSettings.xml did the trick.